# Vaadin Grails: How to use googlemaps add-ons to my project

Tags: java, grails, web, maps, vaadin

I am using vaadin+grails to my project. Now  I need to use the google map and to use a plugin for this in Vaadin but I dont know how to add this adds-on to my project in grails.

There is any guide or tutorial to add an adds-on to vaadin+grail project?

Any cluues or idea ?

Thks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but I think this should work (if you haven't tried it already):

1. Download add-on from the Vaadin website
2. Unzip it and put jar file in the WEB-INF/lib folder inside WebContent folder
3. Compile widgetset
4. Restart your application

as decribed here:

[Vaadin add-on instructions](https://vaadin.com/directory#downloading/googlemaps-add-on/2327/1)

Answer (score 0):

There is an detailed tutorial how to add addons to grails/vaadin

https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Vaadin+on+Grails+-+Widgetset+Compilation